# where to include business logic in listview Class methods

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I am trying to understand Django's class based views (very new to it), especially, ListView. I am struggling to understand where the "business logic should go". Say for example, I have the following class:

```
#views.py
class DisplayListView(ListView):
    model = Cars
    template_name = "searchres_list.html"
    paginate_by = '5'
    context_object_name = "titles"

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(SearchDisplayListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            # custom logic whoch spits out "now". in this example [1 -->10]
    context['now'] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    return context
```

It works fine and I am able to look the [1 --> 10] on my template. However, when I look at the methods available under [ListView](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.4/django.views.generic.list/ListView/) I see that I could probably include my logic in get_queryset method. So, something like:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    # Fetch the queryset from the parent get_queryset
    queryset = super(SearchDisplayListView, self).get_queryset()
             # custom logic whoch spits out "now". in this example [1 -->10]
    queryset = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
            return queryset
```

So, my rather (stupid) question is (or have I got this all completely wrong!), where should the business logic ideally go:

1. def get_context_data
2. def get_queryset

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the best answer to such a subjective question will be: it depends.

My personal algorithm for dealing with the situations like this is the following:

- if you need to add something to the *context* that will be passed to the template, then you don't have a choice actually, because in **get_queryset** method you can only modify the queryset for your ListView. So I use get_context_data in this case.
- but if you're going to perform some *dynamic queryset modifications*, let's say your view can operate on similar model classes and the actual class is determined by the arguments passed into the view, then probably you need to overwrite **get_queryset** method.

Hope I gave you some insights on the topic :)

Comment: Thanks so much for that - I however do not understand your first point - what do you mean by "because in get_queryset method you can only modify the queryset for your ListView" Could you please explain this?. As I see it, I can pass the queryset or the context data to the template - other than the template tags, everything seems to work normal - irrespective of where I put the data - queryset or context. Is this not the case?

Comment: So, when you change the ``queryset`` attribute from ``get_queryset`` method you basically change ``object_list`` in the template. You cannot add, let's say, a form object to the context from ``get_queryset``. You need to use ``get_context_data`` to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks - I understand this now! Accepted your answer :)